# What is the difference between sizeof(int) and sizeof(int*)? Also Is this statement int* numbers[] = {....} correct?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, sizeof

Suppose,

```
int numbers [20];
int * p;
```

I think this is statement is valid

```
p = numbers;
```

But this is not

```
numbers = p;
```

Because `numbers` is an array, operates as a constant pointer, and we cannot assign values to constants. So if we go by this then we cannot use `*numbers` while initializing the array?

Comment: I do not understand "use *numbers while intializing the array".

Comment: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: the title of the question doesn't match the body of the question. Please try to be more precise in the future, so that it's easier to answer and, for other people who share your same doubts, to find a solution to them.

Comment: When Fransesco says *"the title [...] does not match the [...] question."* he is gently suggesting that you need to **fix it**. That's the edit button. Not fixing it shows that you don't respect the time of people who might come along to offer an answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> int numbers [20]; int * p;
>
> I think this is statement is valid
>
> p = numbers;

**Yes**

> But this is not
>
> numbers = p;
>
> Because numbers is an array, operates as a constant pointer, and we cannot assign values to constants.

`numbers` is not a constant pointer, it is a non modifiable `lvalue` so you cannot assign to it.

`sizeof(int)` returns the size of an integer on any particular implementation

`sizeof(int*)` returns the size of a pointer to an integer.

return type of `sizeof()` is `size_t` (unsigned)

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(int)` returns the number of bytes used to store an int

`sizeof(int*)` returns the number of bytes used to store a pointer

To declare an initialise a constant array of ints you can use the following syntax:

```
int numbers[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
```

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(int)` is the size of the data type, `sizeof(int*)` is the size of a pointer to the datatype.

you cannot assign p to numbers, because numbers is declared as a fixed length stack based int array, its not an int pointer(though it can be converted to one)

Answer (score -1):

In simple words

`int numbers [20];` is an integer array

`int * p;` is pointer to an integer; p stores the address it is pointing to

`numbers = p;` is not possible ; both are of different type one is int and other is int*

However `numbers[0] = *p`; is possible ; provided p points at some valid address

Comment: I think you mean `numbers[0] = *p`

Comment: and numbers is not an int it is an array of 20 ints.

Comment: @Kriss, Yes you are right but here I used word "type"